# How to duplicate current process?

Tags: c++, windows, fork, duplication

What's the easiest way to duplicate the current process, to spawn another instance in Windows? I know Linux has `fork()`, but all I need is to run main in the same process again, probably using `CreateProcess()` with the correct arguments.

Comment: `system(argv[0])`? :D (If I got the intention right.)

Comment: What if I run from `WinMain`? Can I simply split `lpCmdLine` and run `system`, or do I need to be in console subsystem? Nope, realized it won't work as I don't want any console window showing up.

Comment: Call `GetCommandLine` and pass it to `CreateProcess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidHeffernan commented:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
::memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
::CreateProcess(NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cygwin implements `fork()`](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/cygwin/fork.cc?rev=1.208&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src) within its managed environment, but even that is an intricate square dance in getting the child to catch up with the parent to accurately replicate POSIX behavior.

It seems like you don't need to emulate `fork()`, but `fork()`/`exec()`.  For that, gathering the environment variables, program parameters and passing them to `CreateProcess()` should be enough.  There are options to copy the file descriptors to the child too.  See `CreateProcess`'s [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).